# Match .jsf web pages

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have the following list and I want to filter out everything *except* the pointed items (Items which ends with `.jsf` and only contain a single `/` in the first position):

```
/js/jquery.js
/contact.jsf   <------
/css/master.css
/index.jsf     <------
/js/Framework.js
/be.xa.resource/file-a-koe.jsf
```

Here's what I was initially trying:

```
^(.(?!.png\.css))*$
\/(.*)[^.jsf]
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Just outputting the /index.jsf and /contact.jsf lines

Answer (score 2):

The below regex would match the  `/index.jsf` and `/contact.jsf` lines,

```
^\/[^\/]*?\.jsf$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iG7fB6/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `\/` Matches a `/` symbol.
- `[^\/]*?` Non-greedy match of any character not of `/` symbol zero or more times.
- `\.jsf` Matches the string `.jsf`
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end.

Comment: I don't how the ? for non-greedy match would matter, but apart from that excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

The matching pattern should be as easy as `^/[^/]*.jsf$` according to your specification.

Well maybe escaping the `/` with `\/`

You may need to wrap it with other commands to serve your exact purpose which isn't really clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex that matches everything except the lines you highlighted:

```
^(?!/[^/]+\.jsf).+$
```

(use with the `gm` options)

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/gX7xU3/1

If you want to match only the lines you highlighted, use this one instead:

```
^/[^/]+\.jsf$
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/kO1lJ3/1